# Is the openssl implementation of ECDH missing something?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, openssl

From the [OpenSSL Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman):

> Also note that the derived shared secret is not suitable for use directly as a shared key. Typically the shared secret is passed through some hash function first in order to generate a key.

My understanding of ECDH is that it generates a very secure shared secret. Why does it have to be hashed too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two reasons:

Reason one is that the ECDH shared secret is not equidistributed; not all values are possible.  In particular, and $x$ that is not a possible solution to the elliptic curve equation cannot happen at all.

Things that use the shared secret (such as AES) are generally assumed to have uniform keys; that is, all keys are possible (and are equiprobable); this isn't possible when using the ECDH shared secret directly.

In practice, it probably doesn't matter; it's hard to conceive of an attack that becomes practical because half of the possible $x$ coordinates are impossible.

Reason two is that not all bits of the ECDH shared secret are actually independent.  If the part of the shared secret bits start going into the $y$ coordinate, then if the attacker somehow gets the $x$ coordinate bits, he gets the $y$ coordinate bits for free (well, one of two possibilities).

We try to avoid revealing some of the bits of the key; however having some bits imply others isn't what we want.  A proper KDF (key derivation function) avoids this possibility.

Note: reason two doesn't apply to all elliptic curves; for example, with Curve25519, we don't explicitly compute the $y$ value, hence that's not available as part of the shared secret.  However, it is present for other curves.

Comment: There are implementations of ECDH that actually use the y coordinate as part of the shared secret?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I thought I remembered seeing one; however a quick search doesn't bring it up...